# Remove element from postgres array if string not exists in sub select

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, subquery

Hello I have a couple of `ltree paths` in `postgres`, now I need to remove a label if it does not exists in a `subquery`.

```
SELECT 
  string_to_array(stacks.path::text, '.') as path 
FROM 
  stacks 
WHERE 
  stacks.id IN (SELECT 
                  subscriptions.stack_id 
                FROM 
                  subscriptions
                WHERE 
                  subscriptions.owner_id = 'user')
```

The path is made up of stacks.id fx 'f34f.23fas.2fs2'. Now I want to remove each label of the path not contained in subscriptions.stack_id. Fx lets say a user has subscribed to the stacks 23fas and 2fs2. Since '23fas' is a child of 'f34f', it´s path will return 'f34f.23fas'. But I want to remove 'f34f' from '23fas'´s path. Meaning I want to remove all labels not contained in subscriptions.stack_id.

This is how far I got, I cant figure out how to remove a element if it does not come up in a given `subquery`.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Which subquery? What label? The code you posted creates an array from the `path` field, and then you want...?

Comment: The question is still unclear without the tables definitions and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `EXISTS` keyword :

```
SELECT string_to_array(st.path::text, '.') as path 
  FROM stacks st 
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM subscriptions sb
     WHERE sb.owner_id = 'user'
       AND sb.stack_id = st.id
  );
```